# How do I inspect enemy unit types?

Tags: warzone-2100

How can I know the type of enemy units in Warzone 2100? It doesn't show anything when you click on it. Seems you can only view types of your own.

Comment: There is a quite active forum on the website http://forums.wz2100.net/.  You might get an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

The current 3.0 release does not support that. It might be a feature, not a bug...